# No manifest found when i run the Push demo code

Tags: push, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

The Message ”No manifest found” Is Displayed When the Push Demo Code Is Run.
I do not yet know why showing this error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem occurs when the agcp plug-in version is earlier than 1.2.1.301. You can solve this problem in the following ways.

1. Upgrade the agcp plug-in to the latest version. Go to buildscript > dependencies and and change the agcp version.

   buildscript { dependencies { classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.2.1.301' } }
2. Add the following configuration to the end of the build.gradle file at the application level to disable the dependency of the agcp plug-in on the manifest file.

   agcp{ manifest false }

After the build.gradle file is modified, Sync Now is displayed in the upper right corner. Click Sync Now and wait until the synchronization is complete.
Or details, see Integrating the HMS SDK in Preparations:
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Guides/Preparations#h1-1575707420071